# kaboom makes page crash and browser asks to block javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use kaboom.js for the first time creating some moving rectangles, but after some time the browser will say that javascript is slowing down everything and blocks it.
I'm guessing this is because when an object exists the screen it doesn't get deleted, but I don't see that in another kaboom scripts

[output](https://mart.ssebastianoo.repl.co)

code

```js
import kaboom from "https://unpkg.com/kaboom@next/dist/kaboom.mjs";

let w, h, direction;
let speed = 20;
let spawnSpeed = 3;
let mode = 'x';

kaboom();

function addRect() {

  switch (mode) {
    case 'x':
      w = 40;
      h = rand(15, 25);
      mode = 'y';
      direction = RIGHT;
      break
    case 'y':
      w = rand(15, 25);
      h = 40;
      mode = 'x';
      direction = DOWN;
      break;
  }

  add([
    rect(w, h),
    area(),
    outline(4),
    pos(
      rand(0, width()-width()/2), 
      rand(0, height()-height()/2)
    ),
    origin("botleft"),
    color(rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255)),
    move(direction, speed),
  ]);
  wait(spawnSpeed, addRect);

  speed += 10;
  if (spawnSpeed >= 1) {
    spawnSpeed -= 0.3;
  };

  speed += 0.3;
}

addRect();
```

Comment: I noticed that it happens when I change tab, wait 3 seconds and get back on it

Comment: Please add all the details by integrating the question text instead of in the comments and please check your link, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see that the whole system slows down it means that surely there is a memory leak or a recursive function calling itself (at least in javascript). The time it takes before everything freezes depends on the amount of RAM you have available.

As you can see from the screenshot kaboom has come to consume 6GB of ram (which causes the slowdown of the entire system) this is because you never remove the rectangles you add and, from what you have written in the code (`spawnSpeed`) you also do it faster and faster.

Also refer to the documentation and avoid copying and pasting other scripts: https://kaboomjs.com/doc#destroy

[image]

Comment: at first I thought that not removing rectangles was the problem, but then I checked a lot of tutorials and none of em did that, thanks a lot!